providesTags of Redux-Toolkit Query is returning an error at the first request, while the succeeding request are saying success
I am trying to implement pagination for the test results page.

undefined testResultsApiSlice.jsx:33
testResultsList testResultsApiSlice.jsx:34
GET http://localhost:3500/testResults? 400 (Bad Request) apiSlice.jsx:19
{ids: Array(3), entities: {…}, totalPages: 2, currentUser: {…}} testResultsApiSlice.jsx:33 (2)
['testResultsList', {…}] testResultsApiSlice.jsx:34 (2)

Above is the result of console logging result (testResultsApiSlice.jsx:33) and arg (testResultsApiSlice.jsx:34) in transformResponse of getTestResults.
when i navigate to the TestResultsList page, the first request returns result as undefined and arg as just testResultsList (chatgpt says that the params which are currentPage, limit, and username are undefined when this request was made so that's why this is happening) after that fail request it says GET http://localhost:3500/testResults? 400 (Bad Request) apiSlice.jsx:19
then a second later it will refetch and say this in the console log

{ids: Array(3), entities: {…}, totalPages: 2, currentUser: {…}} testResultsApiSlice.jsx:33 (2)
['testResultsList', {…}] testResultsApiSlice.jsx:34 (2)

which make it seems like everything is fine, however, no items is being shown in the list and when i check the redux dev tools, the no data is in the testResultsList and it is showing an error message saying that 'Username not found' which i think this came from the first failed request. whenever there's a refetchOnFocus, It will continue to say the error 'Username not found' in redux dev tools even though it is saying this in the console log

{ids: Array(3), entities: {…}, totalPages: 2, currentUser: {…}} testResultsApiSlice.jsx:33 (2)
['testResultsList', {…}] testResultsApiSlice.jsx:34 (2)

also, the process above will repeat whenever i change the page in pagination
TestResultsList.jsx
const TestResultsList = () => {
  const { username } = useAuth();

  const [selectedTestResultId, setSelectedTestResultId] = useState(null);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const itemsPerPage = 10;

  const {
    data: testResults,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetTestResultsQuery(
    ['testResultsList', { page: currentPage, limit: itemsPerPage, username }],
    {
      pollingInterval: 60000,
      refetchOnFocus: true,
      refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    }
  );

apiSlice for testResults
import { createEntityAdapter, createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from '../../app/api/apiSlice';

const testResultsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({});

const initialState = testResultsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const testResultsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTestResults: builder.query({
      query: ([, { page, limit, username }]) => ({
        url: `/testResults`,
        params: { page, limit, username },
        validateStatus: (response, result) => {
          return response.status === 200 && !result.isError;
        },
      }),
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        const loadedTestResults = responseData.testResults.map((testResult) => {
          testResult.id = testResult._id;
          return testResult;
        });
        return {
          ...testResultsAdapter.setAll(initialState, loadedTestResults),
          totalPages: responseData.totalPages,
          currentUser: responseData.currentUser,
        };
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(arg);

        if (result?.ids) {
          return [
            { type: 'TestResult', id: 'LIST' },
            ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: 'TestResult', id })),
          ];
        } else return [{ type: 'TestResult', id: 'LIST' }];
      },
    }),
    addNewTestResult: builder.mutation({
      query: (formData) => ({
        url: '/testResults',
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'TestResult', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    updateTestResult: builder.mutation({
      query: (formData) => ({
        url: '/testResults',
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: formData,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
        { type: 'TestResult', id: arg.id },
      ],
    }),
    deleteTestResult: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        url: '/testResults',
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: { id },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
        { type: 'TestResult', id: arg.id },
      ],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetTestResultsQuery,
  useAddNewTestResultMutation,
  useUpdateTestResultMutation,
  useDeleteTestResultMutation,
} = testResultsApiSlice;

export const selectTestResultsResult =
  testResultsApiSlice.endpoints.getTestResults.select();

const selectTestResultsData = createSelector(
  selectTestResultsResult,
  (testResultsResult) => testResultsResult.data
);

export const {
  selectAll: selectAllTestResults,
  selectById: selectTestResultById,
  selectIds: selectTestResultIds,
} = testResultsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => selectTestResultsData(state) ?? initialState
);

backend controller for getting all test results
const getAllTestResults = async (req,res) => {
  const { page, limit, username } = req.query;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  const currentUser = await User.findOne({ username })
    .select('-password')
    .lean()
    .exec();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Current user not found' });
  }

  const totalTestResults = await TestResult.countDocuments({ user: currentUser._id });
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalTestResults / limit);

  const testResults = await TestResult.find({ user: currentUser._id })
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .lean();

  res.status(200).json({
    totalPages,
    testResults,
    currentUser
  });
}


I solved the issue by not including testResultsList in useGetTestResultsQuery and instead using { page, limit, username }. I removed testResultsList based on advice from ChatGPT and Claude, who suggested that this approach is better for handling dynamic data.
I also discovered that the initial error I encountered, which stated undefined testResultsList, was related to the Prefetch feature. To resolve that, I made sure to pass the same parameters to the prefetch, which fixed the error:
store.dispatch(
      testResultsApiSlice.util.prefetch(
        'getTestResults',
        { page, limit, username },
        {
          force: true,
        }
      )
    );

Now, when I start the app or navigate, all three fields in req.query have values.
Current Issue
Even though the data I receive based on the network requests is correct, I'm observing a behavior in Redux DevTools where the page parameter does not change in the cached query results for getTestResults.
this is what i see in the network

paginate to page 1 request
url: http://localhost:3500/testResults?page=1&limit=10&username=teste
the response is correct and no error
paginate to page 2 request
url: http://localhost:3500/testResults?page=2&limit=10&username=teste
the response is correct and no error

but i noticed that whenever i moved to another page in redux dev tools -> api -> queries ->

▼ getTestResults({"limit":10,"page":1,"username":"teste"}) (pin)
status(pin):"fulfilled" endpointName(pin):"getTestResults"
requestId(pin):"onuIfA8pgFJbmmZoaKiJ7"
▼ original args   page(pin):1
limit(pin):10   username(pin):"teste"
data is correct
startedTimeStamp(pin):1728072720521
fulfilledTimeStamp(pin):1728072720691

why is it that getTestResults({"limit":10,"page":1,"username":"teste"}) is not changing whenever i moved to another page? {"limit":10,"page":1,"username":"teste"} in the pin is just the value of orginal args?  is this normal that it shouldnt be changing for cached or when i moved to another page or it should be changing based on the page?
updated source code
TestResultsList.jsx
    const TestResultsList = () => {   
const { username } = useAuth();
  const [selectedTestResult, setSelectedTestResult] = useState(null);  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);   const [search, setSearch] = useState('');   const [page, setPage] = useState(1);   const limit = 10;

  const {
    data: testResults,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,   } = useGetTestResultsQuery(
    { page, limit, username },
    {
      pollingInterval: 60000,
      refetchOnFocus: true,
      refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    }   );

testResultsApiSlice.jsx
getTestResults: builder.query({
      query: ({ page, limit, username }) => ({
        url: `/testResults`,
        params: { page, limit, username },
        validateStatus: (response, result) => {
          return response.status === 200 && !result.isError;
        },
      }),
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);

        const loadedTestResults = responseData.testResults.map((testResult) => {
          testResult.id = testResult._id;
          return testResult;
        });
        return {
          testResults: loadedTestResults,
          totalPages: responseData.totalPages,
          currentUser: responseData.currentUser,
        };
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result?.testResults) {
          return [
            { type: 'TestResult', id: 'LIST' },
            { type: 'TestResult', id: `PAGE_${arg.page}` },
            ...result.testResults.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'TestResult', id })),
          ];
        } else {
          return [{ type: 'TestResult', id: 'LIST' }];
        }
      },
    }),

testResultsController.js
const getAllTestResults = async (req,res) => {   const { page, limit, username } = req.query;   const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  const currentUser = await User.findOne({ username })
    .select('-password')
    .lean()
    .exec();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Current user not found' });   }

  const totalTestResults = await TestResult.countDocuments({ user: currentUser._id });   const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalTestResults / limit);

  const testResults = await TestResult.find({ user: currentUser._id })
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .lean();

  res.status(200).json({
    totalPages,
    testResults,
    currentUser   }); }


Issue
I suspect the issue is that username from the useAuth hook is not available on the initial render when the useGetTestResultsQuery is called the first time. It's sending an undefined username value to the backend and the getAllTestResults API handler is unable to find a match and returns a 400 error.
const getAllTestResults = async (req,res) => {
  const { page, limit, username } = req.query;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  const currentUser = await User.findOne({ username })
    .select('-password')
    .lean()
    .exec();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Current user not found' });
  }

  ...
}

Solution Suggestion
Use the query's skip option to conditionally call the endpoint only when all the required parameters are available. See Conditional Fetching for details.
Basic Example:
const { username } = useAuth();

...

const {
  data: testResults,
  isLoading,
  isSuccess,
  isError,
  error,
} = useGetTestResultsQuery(
  ['testResultsList', { page: currentPage, limit: itemsPerPage, username }],
  {
    pollingInterval: 60000,
    refetchOnFocus: true,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    skip: !!username // <-- skip query when username is falsey
  }
);

You may also want/care to update the backend logic to better handle potentially bad requests and return more informative errors.
Example:
const getAllTestResults = async (req,res) => {
  const { page = 1, limit = 0, username } = req.query;

  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  if (!username) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No username provided' });
  }

  const currentUser = await User.findOne({ username })
    .select('-password')
    .lean()
    .exec();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Current user not found' });
  }

  const totalTestResults = await TestResult.countDocuments({ user: currentUser._id });
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalTestResults / limit);

  const testResults = await TestResult.find({ user: currentUser._id })
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .lean();

  res.status(200).json({
    totalPages,
    testResults,
    currentUser
  });
}

